# ActionScript 2.0 - Button hover visible false two other buttons

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, visible

I'm making something on Flash with ActionScript 2.0 script. I have a movie clip named **clip**. Inside I have another movie clip named **starters**. In **starters** I have three different buttons which all have a hover layer in them.
What I want those button to do: I want them when I hover on each button to make the other ones be **visible = false**. Then when I hover out to be back at normal.

the buttons are named btn1, btn2, btn3.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that I am unfamiliar with Actionscript 2. However, with a little research, I was able to decipher that strange language and come up with this.

Put this into your action panel within the layer that contains `clip`. We'll not be placing any code on objects today!

```
clip.starters.btn1.onRollOver = hideButtons
clip.starters.btn2.onRollOver = hideButtons
clip.starters.btn3.onRollOver = hideButtons
//set the onRollOver function of each button to function hideButtons()

clip.starters.btn1.onRollOut = showButtons
clip.starters.btn2.onRollOut = showButtons
clip.starters.btn3.onRollOut = showButtons
//set the onRollOut function of each button to function showButtons()

function hideButtons() {
    //repeat the action for all items in "starter"
    for (var Item in clip.starters) {
        //make all items invisible
        clip.starters[Item]._visible = false
    }
    //make the caller of  hideButtons() visible
    this._visible = true
}

function showButtons() {
    //repeat the action for all items in "starter"
    for (var Item in clip.starters) {
        //make everything visible
        clip.starters[Item]._visible = true
    }
}
```

Hope that works for ya. If you want my advice, learn Actionscript 3.0! It's more widely used and has much cleaner code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try this (actionscript 2):

```
var Bt:Array = [_root.clip.starters.btn1, _root.clip.starters.btn2, _root.clip.starters.btn3];

for(i=0; i<Bt.length; i++){
    Bt[i].iv = i;
    Bt[i].onRollOver = function(){
        for( i=0; i<Bt.length; i++ ){ Bt[i]._visible = false; }
        Bt[this.iv]._visible = true;
    };

    Bt[i].onRollOut = function(){
        for( i=0; i<Bt.length; i++ ){ Bt[i]._visible = true; }
    };
};
```

animated:

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;
var Bt:Array = [_root.clip.starters.btn1, _root.clip.starters.btn2, _root.clip.starters.btn3];

for(i=0;i<Bt.length;i++){
    Bt[i].iv = i;
    Bt[i].onRollOver=function(){
        for(i=0;i<Bt.length;i++){
            if(i != this.iv){
            new Tween(Bt[i], "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 100, 0, 15, false);
            new Tween(Bt[i], "_x", Back.easeOut, Bt[i]._x, (Bt[i]._x-10), 1, true);
            }
        }
    };

    Bt[i].onRollOut=function(){
        for(i=0;i<Bt.length;i++){
            if(Bt[i]._alpha ==0){
            new Tween(Bt[i], "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 100, 15, false);
            new Tween(Bt[i], "_x", Back.easeOut, Bt[i]._x, (Bt[i]._x+10), 1, true);
            }
        }
    };
};
```